# What is the use of with clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Please anybody can help me to understand the use of WITH clause

```
WITH T(Id) AS 
(SELECT DISTINCT 
     [IO].[IncidentQuestionId] 
 FROM 
     [dbo].[IncidentValue] AS IV 
 INNER JOIN 
     [dbo].[IncidentOption] AS [IO] ON [IV].[IncidentOptionId] = [IO].[Id]
 WHERE 
     [IV].[IncidentId] = 45
) 
SELECT 
    IQ.*, IC.[Name] AS [IncidentCategory] 
FROM  
    IncidentQuestion] AS IQ 
INNER JOIN 
     T ON [T].[Id] = IQ.[Id] 
INNER JOIN 
     [dbo].[IncidentCategory] AS IC ON IQ.[IncidentCategoryId] = IC.[Id] 
WHERE 
     IQ. [IsOption] = 0 
ORDER BY 
     IC.[OrderId] ASC, IQ.[OrderId] ASC
```

I have the query above which uses the with clause but im not aware of the use of with clause.

thanx

Comment: Have you read it, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: PLease have a look to the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It's a syntax for Common Table Expressions. Read documentation [Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It is used to create a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), which returns a result of a SELECT statement which then can be used in yet another SQL statement. 
I use them to produce better readable SQL code.

Comment: but with clause is not supported in offline web SQL.what is the alternative to clause..

Comment: Writing [Subqueries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213252(v=sql.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For sometimes,`WITH` clause is used to force a query to use an Index.

Comment: How do you force a query to use an Index?

Comment: `select * from table with(index(MySpatialIndex))`

Comment: Ah, yes that's called a [Table Hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx). Not what the OP was asking about, but still an interesting thing to know about.